# Какова этимология слова "спутник"?

Tags: этимология, корень-слова

Нет статей в этимологических словарях.

Answer (score 1):

Как правило, этимологические словари объясняют происхождение основы слова, т.е. его корня.
О происхождении слова сочетающего корень "путь" с приставкой "с" можно прочитать здесь:   https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.35619600-636e5666-fe9e50e9-74722d776562/https/russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5